# How to set class by clicking button in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have html tables.and I would like to change it's `class` by clicking itself.

When I change class,I would like to select each class by clicking `button` behind them

My attempt is like below. How can I pick up `style` by clicking on `button`?

Thanks

```
    $('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      style = $(this);   ??
    })

    $('.click_td').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).AddClass(style);  ??
    });
```

```
    .style1{
        background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .style2 {
        background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;

    }
```

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="click_td">color</td>
        <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="click_btn" class="style1">style1</button>
    <button class="click_btn" class="style2">style2</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `class` attribute more once is not a good practice, we can replace it with `data` attribute. So on each button click, the `data` attribute value is taken, then this value is added to the table td `click_td`..

Now its done on button click, but this can also be replaced with click on `td` ;)

```js
 var $ = jQuery;
 $('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      style = $(this).data().style; 
     $('.click_td').removeClass('style1 style2').addClass(style)
    })
```

```css
    .style1{
        background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .style2 {
        background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;

    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="click_td">color</td>
        <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="click_btn" data-style="style1">style1</button>
    <button class="click_btn" data-style="style2">style2</button>
```

This is the second method, here style is copied to a variable and then applies to the `td` on clicking `td`

```js
var $ = jQuery;
var style ='';
$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  style = $(this).data().style;
})

 $('.click_td').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('style1 style2').addClass(style)
 })
```

```css
.style1 {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.style2 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="click_td">color</td>
    <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="click_btn" data-style="style1">style1</button>
<button class="click_btn" data-style="style2">style2</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not have same attributes  multiple time in elements, if you do so attributes after the first will be ignored silently. Though the best approach will be using ***data-**** attribute here. Also, there is a typo in `AddClass`, should be `addClass`.

You can try the following way:

```js
var style;
$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  style = $(this).data('style'); 
})

$('.click_td').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('style1, style2');
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass(style);  
  style = '';
});
```

```css
.style1{
  background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.style2 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="click_td">color</td>
    <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="click_btn" data-style="style1">style1</button>
<button class="click_btn" data-style="style2">style2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks,Can I select `style` by clicking button? I run code snippet, But I can't reproduce it. when I click`style1` and then click `td`,`td` will turn into `style1`..

Comment: @Heisenberg, I have updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    style = $(this).attr('class');  //will return style1/style2
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to save previous style value when set a style to remove it next time.
2. And there are two `class` attributes in the button elements.
3. Consider using `innerText` instead of `class` value.

```js
let prevStyle = '';
let style = '';

$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  prevStyle = style;
  style = $(this).text();
})

$('.click_td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass(prevStyle);
  $(this).addClass(style);
});
```

```css
.style1 {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.style2 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="click_td">color</td>
    <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="click_btn style1">style1</button>
<button class="click_btn style2">style2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(()=>{
var style = $(this).attr('class');   
$('.click_btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      style = $(this).attr('class');   
    })

    $('.click_td').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(style);
      $(this).attr('class','');   
      $(this).addClass(style);  
    });
    })
```

```css
 .style1{
        background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .style2 {
        background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 5px;

    }
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="click_td">color</td>
        <td class="click_td">color 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="click_btn style1">style1</button>
    <button class="click_btn style2">style2</button>
```